# jquery select by class then match value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
  <li class="somename">2</li>
  <li class="somename">3</li>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
</ul>
```

then I have a value like this

```
var myvalue = 1;
```

I want to compare myvalue with all the `$(".somename).text()` to find the matching ones and change the text of the matching to something else like below

```
<ul>
  <li class="somename">changed</li>
  <li class="somename">2</li>
  <li class="somename">3</li>
  <li class="somename">changed</li>
</ul>
```

`$(".somename").text()` give me all the text in a string like 1231

and I tried to for loop

```
       for(i=0;i<$(".somename").length;i++){
            if(myvalue == $(".somename")[i].text()){
                $(this).text("changed")
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you want to compare `myvalue` with the string inside the `class` attribute?

Comment: @Pragun I want to compare with the values in the list. $(".somename).text() not the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.somename').each(function() {

  var value = $(this).text();

  if (value == "1") {
    $(this).text("Changed")

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
  <li class="somename">2</li>
  <li class="somename">3</li>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
</ul>
```

1. Use `.each()` to loop through all elements with the class.
2. Have a condition , if met change the text

Answer (score 1):

When using the bracket object property accessor (`[]`) on a jQuery object you are accessing the underlying object in the collection so `.text()` would not be available as that is not a function on the underlying DOM object (you should have seen an error on your console)

You can use jQuery [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to loop through the collection

```
$(".somename").each(function(){
    //unless you are going to be doing more jQuery DOM stuff
    //no need to wrap in jQuery just access the innerText
    if(myvalue == this.innerText){
       this.innerText = "changed";
    }
});
```

If you dont want to use the [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method and just use the `for loop` you would need to use either [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or similar method to get the jQuery wrapped object at a particular index

```
var elements = $(".somename");
for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    let element = elements.eq(i);
    if(myvalue == element.text()){
      element.text("changed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
$(".somename").each(function(e, val ){
       if (myvalue == e.text){

        //do stuff here
      }    
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out but FYI I've not tried this on my own system.

```
var myvalue = 1;
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
    if(myvalue == lists[i].innerHTML){
       //change your text here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .each function.

```
var myvalue=1;
$('.somename').each(function(){      
  if($(this).text()==myvalue){
    $(this).text('changed');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things here
1. When you search any DOM element .Try to copy it into a variable and then use it .DOM search is a costly operation
2.When you are using for loop,this would point to window object

check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someoneArray=$(".somename");
  var someoneArrayLength=someoneArray.length;
  var myValue=1;
  for(var i=0;i<someoneArrayLength;i++){
    var value=parseInt($(someoneArray[i]).text());
   console.log(this)
            if(myValue == value){
              alert("here");
               $(someoneArray[i]).text("changed");
            }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
  <li class="somename">2</li>
  <li class="somename">3</li>
  <li class="somename">1</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps